# How to turn Linux kernel block layer into a module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to modify the [block layer](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BLOCK.html) code to add some new functionality into it, but since it is compiled with the kernel, every time I make code changes I have to recompile and reboot the system.

Is there a way that I can isolate the block layer code and compile it as a separate module? If that's too much to ask, is there a general way to do this for any built-in kernel feature?